# Spring Cloud Gateway in CloudFoundry

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-gateway

I've been trying to get my apps to run after deploing them to a CloudFoundry instance. The instance I'm using will not allow to perform requests using http (they will simply timeout) so I have to route all requests to https.

The components/versions I am using are:

- Java 10
- Spring Boot 2.0.4.RELEASE/Spring Cloud Finchley.SR1
- spring-cloud-gateway
- spring-cloud-config-server
- spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka

The failing config

**EurekaClient Config** (in gateway and the backend where the gw should route to)

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${DISCOVERY_SERVICE_URL:http://localhost:8061}/eureka/
  instance:
    hostname: ${vcap.application.uris[0]:localhost}
    nonSecurePortEnabled: false
    securePortEnabled: true
    securePort: ${server.port}
    statusPageUrl: https://${eureka.instance.hostname}/actuator/info
    healthCheckUrl: https://${eureka.instance.hostname}/actuator/health
    homePageUrl: https://${eureka.instance.hostname}/
    secure-virtual-host-name: https://${vcap.application.application_uris[0]}
```

**Gateway Config**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
      routes:
      - id: user-service
        uri: lb://user-service
        predicates:
        - Path=/user/**
        filters:
        - RewritePath=/user/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}
```

Things I have already tried:

- Using `lb:https://user-service` like described in [docs](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/single/spring-cloud-gateway.html#_routetorequesturl_filter) -> Will have no effect as far as I can see
- Use real urls to the apps (`uri: https://user-service.cf-instance.io`) -> Routing works as expected.

But I do not want to define the urls in my config, they should returned by eureka and build up correctly by the gateway.

Thanks in advance

Edit:

Here is the output of `/eureka/apps`
https://pastebin.com/WP3b6PQG

I am currently working to get the current code into GitHub I will edit this post when I've found the time to get a clear state.

Edit 2:

You can find the full example (With SpringCloudGateway, Eureka, ...) at [my GitHub](https://github.com/konraifen88-home/home-monitor-aio/tree/c2d3f660f654417aca0de2fed915d33b960c0fac)
This is an running example, the applied config will not use the Eureka. To use Eureka the `gateway-service-cloud.yml` in config service has to be adopted.

`- id: user-service
        uri: lb://user-service`

<strike>Please ignore the documentation service, this will not work yet, I first need to rewrite the path.</strike>

Comment: Are there services registered with a secure port in eureka?

Comment: Yes, the services are properly registered in the eureka dashboard. When I click the ID in the dashboard I am redirected to the health endpoint of the service.
Also the response to the gateway contains the correct uri, but without the schema itself. So I think that there is something missing in the Gateway Config that the schema can/will be set to https.

Comment: Can you show the output of `<eurekaserver>/eureka/apps`?

Comment: I've edited the post to add the information you asked for. Today I did another test. I deployed the apps with 2 different configurations. 
The first one was with fix https urls and the other with lb config. The generated xml for `/eureka/apps` is exactly the same (except ip, timestamps and id).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found out the solution during fixing the "routing" problem with my `documentation-service`.

My problem was setting the property `eureka.instance.securePort` to `${server.port}`. This property has to be set to `443` (the default 443 is not applied when nothing is set). When adding this to my configurations everything works as expected after pushing my application.

Comment: Hi @Konrad , I am facing the same issue. Could you tell me in which service did you set `eureka.instance.securePort` to `443 ` ? Gateway service or the other microservices ?

Comment: Hey @jackfr0st. Have a look into my commit history. I've set all the `securePorts` to 443.
https://github.com/konraifen88-home/home-monitor-aio/commit/4df625a8cf52b64d89d940efe495bbbd44024913